# Animated ProgressBar in ListView

Tags: android, jquery, listview, animation, android-arrayadapter

I've created a list with 5 items. The list items have a Layout with a cirlce, a text an a progressbar. The Progressbar should be animated if a certain falue is TRUE. If this value is FALSE. The progressbar should be empty (progress.setProgress(0)).
The animation is as fallows:

```
final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(power, "progress", currentWP.power());
animation.setDuration(2000); // 2 Sekunden
animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

power is the progressbar that should be animated and currentWP.power() is the value where the animation should be stopped.
The progressbar maximum is set to 100.

The problem is that the animation starts for the fist listitem although the value is FALSE and the currentWP.power is 0. The animation END-value is the same as the END-value of the last listitem.

ListView:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WP> {

    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(Overview_Activity.this, R.layout.list_item, windparks);
        //Log.d("MyList","start");
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Log.d("View","start");
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        final WP currentWP = windparks.get(position);

        //WP-Name
        TextView name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.WP_name);
        name.setText(currentWP.getname());

        //WP-Icon
        final ImageView status = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.error_icon);

        //WP-Produktion

        //Log.d("WP", currentWP.getname());
        //Log.d("Power", String.valueOf(currentWP.power()));

        final ProgressBar power = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.power_overview);
        //power.setProgress(0);

            if (!currentWP.getstatus()) {
                status.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_error);
                power.setProgress(0);
                name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            } else {
                status.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_ok);
                //power.setProgress(currentWP.power());
                Log.d(currentWP.getname(), String.valueOf(currentWP.getstatus()));
                name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                //Animation erstellen und starten
                final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(power, "progress", 0, currentWP.power());
                animation.setDuration(2000); // 2 Sekunden
                animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animation.start();

            }

        return itemView;
    }
```

I also tried it without the animation. I set the progress the the certain value. This worked fine. But I would like to animate the progressbar.